# AJAX won't run ajaxStart or load the script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So my code looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/qBZMh/4/

Now, on this it won't add the class "active" because it can't find the requested file, for me it finds the file but it won't run the file. My PHP-file look like this:

```
<?php
$time = time();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends
(userid, userid2, `type`, `date`) VALUES
('1', '2', '1', '$time' )") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addfriend").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "snippets/profile_addfriend.php",
            context: document.body
        }).done(function () {
            $("#addfriend").addClass("active");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on({
        ajaxStart: function () {
            $(this).addClass("loading");
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            //$(this).removeClass("loading");
        }
    });
});
```

There should be variables instead of numbers but just to see if it actually runs I have removed that.

So, the problems are:

1. It finds the PHP-file but it won't run the script.
2. It doesn't show a loading bar, I might have understood this wrong but I want it so my button gets replaced by the loading bar and then appears again when the script have been executed.

Answer (score 1):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to
>   document.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

```
 $(document).on({ //no need to be inside document ready handler!
        ajaxStart: function () { alert('yy');
            $('body').addClass("loading");
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            $('body').removeClass("loading");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get the alert but it doesn't seem like it adds the loading class. I cannot see it and still the PHP-script doesn't load.

Comment: If your ajax request is wrong, ajaxStop will be called instantly so the class is removed. Try to test it by yourself, what if you remove the removeClass()? Is the body get class "loading"?

Comment: What give you the console network tab? Is your php script returning error?

Comment: I've got it working now, it didn't have a database connection because another script I had somehow prevented it. Now I have done so it shows the loading bar correctly but in order to replace it I have to remove the text of the button this code is runned when ajaxStart:
$('#addfriend').addClass("loading").removeAttr("addfriend").html('');
and this when ajaxStop:
$('.addfriend').removeClass("loading").addAttr("addfriend").html('Add as friend');

But it won't add the text "Add as friend" I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addAttr'"

Comment: Ya, Object [object Object] has no method 'addAttr'"  What don't you understand in this statement? I think you want: $('.addfriend').removeClass("loading").attr("addfriend",true).html('Add as friend');   But again, addfriend is not a valid html attribute. For this, you should use data() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have no fallback for a 404. If it cannot find it, it will prompt a 404 not found error. 
you could add

```
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
},
```

to add a catch for a 404.

Comment: Where more exactly do I put it?